# Выдает ошибку в библиотеке youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Вот сама ошибка:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by <HTTPError 429: 'Too Many Requests'>); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

Саму библиотеку я уже обновил и у меня сейчас стоит самая новая версия

И как я еще раз попробую добавить музыку то мне выдаст такую же ошибку. Она будет появляться пока я не перезапущу бота
Эта ошибка выдается когда я пытаюсь включить музыку через команду.

Бывает такое что не выдает эту ошибку и все работает хорошо.

Что нужно сделать чтобы больше не было такой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube посчитал что вы делаете слишком много запросов.

Вам необходимо снизить кол-во запросов. Либо ограничив кол-во запросов к YouTube путём, например, ограничения использования команды (cooldown), либо путём добавления кэширования

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 20, commands.BucketType.member)
```

Нашел решения с помощью такой строки